# Fedora's firewall-cmd shows more available services than configured

Tags: fedora, fedora-20, firewalld

So yeah, configuring Fedora 20's firewall-cmd. Tried to limit inbound traffic to only http, https, and ssh. However, the machine still responds to pings, and the --get-service command shows a laundry list of things I do not use.

Why the disconnect?

Is the --get-service command accurate, or is the --list-services command accurate?

If the latter, why does ping get through?

```
[root@build-node httpd]# firewall-cmd --get-service
amanda-client bacula bacula-client dhcp dhcpv6 dhcpv6-client dns ftp high-availability http https imaps ipp ipp-client ipsec kerberos kpasswd ldap ldaps libvirt libvirt-tls mdns mountd ms-wbt mysql nfs ntp openvpn pmcd pmproxy pmwebapi pmwebapis pop3s postgresql proxy-dhcp radius rpc-bind samba samba-client smtp ssh telnet tftp tftp-client transmission-client vnc-server wbem-https
[root@build-node httpd]# firewall-cmd --get-active-zone
public
  interfaces: eth0 eth1 eth2
[root@build-node httpd]# firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-services
http https ssh
```

Additionally, excerpts from iptables -L -n.

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
INPUT_direct  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
INPUT_ZONES  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain INPUT_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
IN_public  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]
IN_public  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]
IN_public  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]
IN_public  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto]

Chain IN_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 ctstate NEW
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`--get-services` shows all services that firewalld is aware of, not those that you have opened ports for.

`--list-services` shows those that you have opened ports for.

You can see in the `iptables` listing that only ports 22, 80 and 443 are open, which is what you said you wanted.

Finally, about pings: All ICMP is allowed by default with firewalld (as it's usually a bad idea to block it unless you *really* know what you're doing). If you truly want to "block pings" then you have to do so explicitly. You can use `--get-icmptypes` to see the list of ICMP types that firewalld knows about, and `--add-icmp-block` to block one of them. Be sure you're on the console of the machine in case you lock yourself out.

Comment: Great, thanks. I don't really mind ping being available, just didn't like something unexpected being allowed.

Comment: Should be `--get-services`.